# Saving a rails has_many association using multiple keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, model-associations

I have the following models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_recommendation_sets, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :recommendation_sets, :through => :product_recommendation_sets
end

class RecommendationSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_recommendation_sets, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :products, :through => :product_recommendation_sets

  has_many :recommendations 
end

class Recommendation < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :recommendation_set
end
```

And am adding `recommendations` `recommendations_set` like so:

```
p = Product.find_by_wmt_id(product) || Product.create( ItemData.get_product_data(product) )     
recommendation =  find_by_rec_id(rec_id) || create( ItemData.get_product_data(rec_id) )        
                rec_set =  RecommendationSet.find_or_create_by_rating_set_id_and_model_version_and_product_id(rating_set.id, model_version, p.id)
                sec_set.update_attributes(
                :rating_set_id => rating_set.id,
                :product_id    => p.id,
                :model_version => model_version,
                :notes => note
                )

                sec_set.recommendations << recommendation
                sec_set.save

prs = ProductRecommendationSet.find_or_create_by_recommendation_set_id_and_rating_set_id_and_product_id(rec_set .id, rating_set.id, p.id,)
            prs.update_attributes(
            :recommendation_set_id => rec_set.id, 
            :rating_set_id => rating_set.id,
            :product_id => p.id
            )
```

This works as expected, however my problem is that I have multiple `recommendation_sets` which belong to multiple `products`, and each of the `recommendation_sets` may have the same `recommendation`. By saving each `recommendation` to a `recommendation_set` as I am currently doing, if two `recommendation_sets` have the same `recommendation`, only one of the sets will add that `recommendation`. Is there anyway of saving each `recommendation` to multiple `recommendation_sets` using a secondary id, such as save by `recommendation_id_and_product_id`, or would I need to change this releationship to a `has_many :through`?

Comment: By the by, for the first line of code, if you want to simplify it a bit, you can use the [first_or_create](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create) method. So you would do something like this: 

`Product.where(:wmt_id=>product).first_or_create(ItemData.get_product_data(product)`. 

This will also work for the `ProductRecommendationSet` line further down; rather than using that long `find_or_create_by_foo_and_bar_and_baz_and....`, you can stuff that all in a `.where`, and call `first_or_create`

Comment: Additionally, you've got an extra comma at the end of the `ProductRecommendationSet` creation line, inside the parentheses. Also, 2nd line in the creation block, you have `find_by_rec_id` and `create` by themselves; what models are being created on that line? Finally, 4th line in the same block, you have a variable called `sec_set` but I don't see that anywhere. Is that a typo or a variable defined somewhere else?

Comment: And finally, can you clarify if my interpretation of your question is correct: I have 2 recommendation sets (RS1 and RS2), both of them point to the same Recommendation (R). You're saying that, given the code you have above, if you attempt to save those two recommendation sets, only one of them gets saved (meaning, RS1 gets saved, RS2 does not)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Clarification: I have two recommendation sets RS1 & RS2 and multiple recommendations which belong to them, R1..Rn. How can I save R1 to RS1 while also saving R1 to RS2. What is happening now is that R1 is being saved to RS2 but not RS1, because R1 can only store RS2's id (only one reference id column on my recommendations table). I think I may have to go with a has_many through relationship so I can create the association using more than just one Recommendation Set ID.

Comment: Oh ok, I think I understand. I'm going to post an answer; let me know whether I've understood it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your clarification, I think you basically have a many-to-many relationship between `RecommendationSet` and `Recommendation`. Presently, you have a one-to-many.

There are a couple of options:

1. Use the `has_and_belongs_to_many` method in both models to describe the relationship;
2. Manually create a "join" model and then give both `RecommendationSet` and `Recommendation` a `has_many` to this join model (with two corresponding `belongs_to` lines in the join model pointing to the other two models);
3. A `has_many ... :through` style, like you mentioned

Note that the first two options require you to have a join table.

If you require additional information on the join table/model, I tend to go with the 2nd option. Otherwise, either the first or third are perfectly valid.

Ryan Bates of RailsCasts made an episode about this here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many

And some more information from the Rails documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Many-to-many

In short, if you don't need extra info on the join, I think your idea of the `has_many ... :through` is perfectly fine.

Let me know whether that helps